# What are the disadvantages of using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I hear that Visual Basic 6 is not good.

I want to make very generic program. Would Visual Basic 6 suffice?

Comment: What do you mean by "very generic programs"?

Comment: Why would VB6 be good for generic programs?

Answer (score 19):

The very first reason is that Microsoft no longer offers support for VB6 development. This product is end of life.

http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2971

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708

Comment: YES YES YES!  Don't use VB6!  This alone should suffice as the first and last reason to not use it.  Throw in the relatively crummy libraries compared to .Net and the clumsier, less expressive syntax, and I can't come up with a single _good_ reason to _use_ VB6.

Comment: I'd only use it for something really trivial, non-long term maintenance, and I need something done fast because it'd be the only language i'd know, but does it not my case...

Comment: Well, then you can only use it on old Windows versions, as it does not worth the while to use it on Windows 7 if you hit anything Microsoft won't fix.

Comment: The IDE is no longer supported. The runtime is still supported.

Comment: Added another link which better states the key points.

Answer (score 6):

It worked well in its time, but it doesn't have a simple path forward.  If you want to migrate to a newer version of Visual Basic, it can be a fair bit of work.  And no new tools are being developed for it.

Answer (score 4):

If your major interest is in a cheap VB development environment, as previously mentioned, the [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/default.aspx) editions are free from Microsoft.

I can't think of many good reasons to use VB6 instead of one of the express versions.  Also as previously noted whatever VB skills you learn won't be particularly portable and the apps you build won't be able easily to migrate to more up-to-date environments.

Answer (score 2):

I will also have a look at Real Basic.  It is a cross-compiler and your applications will run on different platforms.  There are many options available in the market.  It all depends on what your definition of "generic program" is.

[Real Basic](http://www.realsoftware.com/realbasic/)

Answer (score 2):

I have ever listen bad comments about Visual Basic 6 programming, I have written thousands of VB6 lines of code, in the same manner I have written code in object oriented languages (C++, C#, Java). But It seems to me that VB6 is a very good programming language, because **it allows you to write powerful-simple applications**. VB6 syntax is easier that C/C++ syntax but C#/Java aren't so much difficult that VB6. Also developing enterprise application is such new languages (Java, C#, VB.Net, Rubby) is easier that VB6 because they rely on Frameworks, **every body can write C#/Java code that function, but it requires, tricks, good practices and some of imagination to write VB6 strong and rehusable code**.

**Many developers become quickly frustrating by using VB6 and then are happy programmers using C#/Java**. All depends on practices and discipline there is no bad language, each language was designed with some purposes on mind, by selecting the appropriate language, problems solving could be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Forget VB6. It's a dead system. No support, no future. Use the Visual Basic Express Edition, as suggested above. It's free, useful, and about as "generic" as it gets anymore.
Or, you could use something even better: Python ([www.python.org](http://www.python.org)). Or IronPython. (www.codeplex.com/IronPython).
Much better system.

Comment: The VB6 IDE is no longer supported. The runtime is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you are approaching the programming world, and you want to do some programs, Visual Basic is more than sufficient.
Once you learned it, you will keep to use it.

As Visual Basic Express (which is the version that was before called Visual Basic .NET) is given free from Microsoft, maybe you could be interested in that.

Comment: Visual Basic Express editions (2005, 2008) are all for VB.NET, not for VB6.

Comment: That is true. I just wanted to make clear the difference, which could not be clear to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "Generic Programs" there are plenty of other environments/languages that you can create simple apps with, even at no cost.

Visual Basic is old and no longer supported by Microsoft, sounds like you may just have access to a copy.

Yes you certainly can create generic programs with it, but where do you go from there? Is this hobby programming?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say VB6 is still ok for (throw away) prototyping and probably better than VB.NET in that regard.  A larger problem is the lack of true inheritance and being able to use the idioms available in .NET.  As such it makes writing clean and maintainable code more difficult.

Comment: I disagree. WPF and VB.Net is one of the fastest prototyping tools I know of.

Comment: depends what you're doing.  It's easier to set up networking by dropping a winsock control on a form.  I personally find VB6 faster to prototype applications than VB.NET, but my company doesn't do WPF.  Although I said VB was OK to prototype with, it's not good to develop with, I guess you're disagreeing with that?

Answer (score 0):

even bill gates wont suggest you to use it!! they stopped its support to make migration to newer versions faster. So now dont go and start a new project in a dead language. also there is no backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, Microsoft's support for VB6 has been discontinued. But no company "supports" C, so I would say that's not really a reason inherent to the language.

Another reason is support for objected oriented programming, which may or may not be important to you. To me, it is.
VB6 is handicapped in this area. It doesn't really support interfaces. Also, arrays are some pain to work with. Checking whether an array has been properly intialized (a fairely trivial task, imho) involves some workarounds. It's not as simple as

```
If myArray Is Not Nothing Then ...
```

If you already know some Visual Basic syntax, then switching to VB.NET shouldn't be hard. You'll just have learn your way around the framework class library.

Comment: The VB6 IDE is no longer supported. The runtime is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

If someone tell you for **any** language the it's "*not good*" then just erase this person from your contact list.

There no good/bad languages. **Horses for the courses**.

As for disadvantages - you'll find such in **any** language.

Answer (score 0):

vb 6 is very good to approach the programmation with object and to know basic structure of programming . If you understand one language you CAN know the other. Is not important only the programm language, but  the FLOW of data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as beginner programming is concerned, I suggest to start playing around with VB6, for its BASIC programming style, GUI that is not so complicated, and a bunch of code is available online. I myself start coding using VB6.

But honest advice, if you want to find a job, start learning C++, C#, JAVA, HTML, PHP, and better yet, ANDROID DEVELOPMENT.

Even if VB6 is not suitable for our life today, you can still stick to its new generation: VISUAL STUDIO - which offers a more complex GUI, yet more flexible platform. It offers VB.NET, C# and creates your own Database with powerful connection.

Just want to thank VB6 for teaching me how to code!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) as a [modern replacement for Visual Basic](http://blog.xojo.com/2013/06/19/a_great_alternative_to_visual_basic/). It is as easy to use as VB6, but also build cross-platform desktop apps, web apps and iOS apps.